# Entity Framework Core fluent api One-To-Many and One-To-One produces duplicate foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api, entity-framework-core-migrations

I'm changing my ASP.NET MVC project to ASP.NET Core MVC with Entity Framework Core and Fluent API. When I try to configure a one-to-one and one-to-many relationship, it generates duplicate foreign key columns in the dependent table.

For example: I have this in my context's `OnModelCreating` method:

```
builder.Entity<Session>()
       .HasKey(s=>s.Id);
builder.Entity<Session>()
       .Property(s=>s.CourseId)
       .IsRequired();
builder.Entity<Session>()
       .HasOne<Course>()
       .WithMany(c => c.Sessions)
       .HasForeignKey(s=>s.CourseId)
       .IsRequired();
```

Session model is like this:

```
public class Session
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // foreign key 
    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    // navigation properties
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

Course model is like this:

```
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public ICollection<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
}
```

Instead of getting this back in the migration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity("Blackboard.Models.DomainModels.Session", b =>
    {
        b.Property<int>("Id")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        b.Property<int>("CourseId");

        b.HasKey("Id");

        b.HasIndex("CourseId");

        b.ToTable("Sessions");
   });
```

I get this:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity("Blackboard.Models.DomainModels.Session", b =>
    {
        b.Property<int>("Id")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        b.Property<int>("CourseId");

        b.Property<int?>("CourseId1");

        b.HasKey("Id");

        b.HasIndex("CourseId");

        b.HasIndex("CourseId1");

        b.ToTable("Sessions");
   });
```

So even though I put `.IsRequired();` for the relationship, the relationship seems to be made optional and an optional `CourseId1` is added to the table.

The application is developed on Mac OSX with Visual Studio for Mac.

I've been configuring this for so long, I only found something for Entity Framework instead of Entity Framework Core. They two don't configure the same way. Can someone help me please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a fix. I changed the context to:

```
builder.Entity<Session>()
   .HasOne(s=>s.Course)
   .WithMany(c => c.Sessions)
   .HasForeignKey(s=>s.CourseId)
   .IsRequired();
```

I remember I saw somewhere saying that if there is only one navigation property, then `.HasOne<Type>()`(no parameters passed) can be used. Obviously, it's not working.  So always use lambda parameter in `.HasOne`.

Comment: Always use the **correct** overload. If you have navigation property, use lambda overload. If you don't have navigation property, use parameterless overload.

Comment: This helped set me straight... I really wish they would just nail down the syntax already. It's an improvement over the dotnet framework version, but this is almost as confusing at times.